# Parse a List to an MDX Query (List in MDX M Power BI)

Tags: mdx, powerbi, m

I'm looking for a way to integrate a previously retrieved list as an input for a FILTER in a MDX query. I currently have the following code:

```
segment_var = Segment,
mdxQ = "SELECT 
            NON EMPTY ( { [Measures].[AMT] * [Forecast Type].[Forecast Type].[Forecast Level 2] } ) DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_NAME ON COLUMNS, 
            NON EMPTY ( {
                [Period].[Year Month Name].[Name] *
                [PL Spec].[PL Spec].[Level 6 Code].allmembers
            } ) ON ROWS
        FROM (
            SELECT ( { [Forecast Type].[Current Indicator].&[Y] } ) ON COLUMNS 
            FROM ( 
                SELECT ( { [PL Spec].[PL Spec].[Level 1 Code].&[101] } ) ON COLUMNS
                FROM [AIR]))
        WHERE (
            FILTER([Management Structure - Segment].[Management Structure - Segment].[MS Level 5].ALLMEMBERS , [Management Structure - Segment].[Management Structure - Segment].currentmember.name=""" & segment_var & """))",
```

Segment on row 1 used to be a single value parameter but I want to use a list of segments (listSegment) as a reference instead so the result filters multiple segments. I've tried WHERE IN solutions but I can't seem to get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Error:

```
Expression.Error: We cannot apply operator & to types Text and List.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve the issue in the following way:

1. Make the list of values to be filtered in the query
2. Transpose and combine the list using ", "
3. Convert to single variable

Code:

```
    Convert = 
    Table.ToList(
        Table.Transpose(
            Table.FromList(#"Distinct")), 
        Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(", ")),
    Var = List.First(Convert)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to generate segment_var as

```
{[Management Structure - Segment].[Management Structure - Segment].[1], [Management Structure - Segment].[Management Structure - Segment].[2], ...}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? Currently my main challenge is getting it into the MDX query code, I've tried generating segment_var in various ways including the one you mentioned but I lack the MDX experience to get it to properly use the array. EDIT: The error I get is: We cannot apply operator & to types Text and List.

Comment: Could you please provide an array?

Comment: listSegment = {[Management Structure - Segment].[Management Structure - Segment].&[283],
[Management Structure - Segment].[Management Structure - Segment].&[706],
[Management Structure - Segment].[Management Structure - Segment].&[713]}

Comment: Try without ampersands: {[Management Structure - Segment].[Management Structure - Segment].[283], [Management Structure - Segment].[Management Structure - Segment].[706], [Management Structure - Segment].[Management Structure - Segment].[713]}

Comment: Doesn't fix the syntax issue in the MDX query unfortunately. Furthermore the input for the user defined variable segment_var has to refer to a list generated in a previous query in the end. Currently the link between list and segment_var seemed to be fine.

Comment: I'm afraid that MDX within PowerBI isn't really ready for wide usage like passing parameters. You have to pre-load the data and filter within the report. See: http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-does-passing-a-parameter-to-MDX-works/m-p/154013#M66644